# Can't get getExceptionTraceAsString() to work. Errors still truncated. Magento 1.9 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql

I followed [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418819/steve) post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949345/how-can-i-get-the-full-string-of-php-s-gettraceasstring) to try to show the full MySQL query in the log, instead of it being truncated, like this: ('INSERT INTO `fa...', Array)

I've triple checked the process, but it isn't working. Is there anything additional that needs to be done to achieve this?

Comment: My impression (but I never checked) is, that xdebug is changing things here.

Comment: hmm strange as I haven't setup xdebug

Comment: I think this question would be much more appreciated (and had a bigger audience) on stackoverflow.com. It's no specific Magento question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PHP question and not Magento specific.

Comment: Eleventy you should try with xdebug, maybe it changes something :-)